# More efficient way to change long/short position in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithmic-trading

Is there a more efficient way to change long/short positions in pandas than what I have come up with below?

The gist of the logic:

- Position is `np.nan` until there is a buy (+1) or sell (-1) signal.
- The first time there is a buy/sell (+/-1) signal, set the position to that number.
- After the first position has been set, carry it forward. Only add onto the position if of the same sign. Else, change the sign and set to the sign times 1 (i.e. if current position is 3 and then you get a sell (-1) signal, then the position goes from 3 to -1. vice versa, if position is -3 and there is a buy signal, position goes from -3 to 1).

### My Code

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'buy_sell': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, -1, np.nan, -1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, -1],
    'position': np.nan
})

for i, r, in df.iterrows():
    buy_sell = r['buy_sell']

    # Check if first index
    if i != 0:
        last_position = df.loc[i-1, 'position']

        if np.isnan(buy_sell):
            df.loc[i, 'position'] = last_position
        else:
            if np.isnan(last_position) or last_position * buy_sell <= 0:
                df.loc[i, 'position'] = buy_sell
            else:
                df.loc[i, 'position'] = last_position + buy_sell
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'position'] = buy_sell
```

### Expected solution

```py
df_expected = pd.DataFrame({
    'buy_sell': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, -1, np.nan, -1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, -1],
    'position': [np.nan, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, -1, -1, -2, -2, 1, 1, -1],
})
```

```
    buy_sell  position
0        NaN       NaN
1        1.0       1.0
2        NaN       1.0
3        1.0       2.0
4        NaN       2.0
5        NaN       2.0
6        1.0       3.0
7       -1.0      -1.0
8        NaN      -1.0
9       -1.0      -2.0
10       NaN      -2.0
11       1.0       1.0
12       NaN       1.0
13      -1.0      -1.0
```

*Note: The code I have above produces the expected data frame. I am asking if there is a more efficient/better way of doing what I have done above.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
df["position"] = df.buy_sell.groupby(\
                      df.buy_sell.bfill()\
                      .diff()\
                      .abs()\
                      .cumsum()\
                 ).cumsum().ffill()
```

**Output**

```
df
     buy_sell   position
0         NaN        NaN
1      1.0000     1.0000
2         NaN     1.0000
3      1.0000     2.0000
4         NaN     2.0000
5         NaN     2.0000
6      1.0000     3.0000
7     -1.0000    -1.0000
8         NaN    -1.0000
9     -1.0000    -2.0000
10        NaN    -2.0000
11     1.0000     1.0000
12        NaN     1.0000
13    -1.0000    -1.0000
```

---

**Explanation**

Basically, you want some sort of `cumsum` by groups created by the sign changes in the column, then, first of all we need to find those changes:

```
>>> df.buy_sell.bfill().diff().abs()
0           NaN
1        0.0000
2        0.0000
3        0.0000
4        0.0000
5        0.0000
6        0.0000
7        2.0000
8        0.0000
9        0.0000
10       2.0000
11       0.0000
12       2.0000
13       0.0000
```

As you can see, every `2` is a sign change. Now, usign [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) we can assign a group to every row

```
>>> df.buy_sell.bfill().diff().abs().cumsum()
0           NaN
1        0.0000
2        0.0000
3        0.0000
4        0.0000
5        0.0000
6        0.0000
7        2.0000
8        2.0000
9        2.0000
10       4.0000
11       4.0000
12       6.0000
13       6.0000
```

So, every row with 0 is a group, every row with 2 is a group, and so on. With this, we can directly use [`pandas.Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) with [`pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
>>> df.buy_sell.groupby(df.buy_sell.bfill().diff().abs().cumsum()).cumsum()
0           NaN
1        1.0000
2           NaN
3        2.0000
4           NaN
5           NaN
6        3.0000
7       -1.0000
8           NaN
9       -2.0000
10          NaN
11       1.0000
12          NaN
13      -1.0000
```

All we need now is to propagate last valid observation forward to next valid with [`pandas.Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
>>> df.buy_sell.groupby(df.buy_sell.bfill().diff().abs().cumsum()).cumsum().ffill()
0           NaN
1        1.0000
2        1.0000
3        2.0000
4        2.0000
5        2.0000
6        3.0000
7       -1.0000
8       -1.0000
9       -2.0000
10      -2.0000
11       1.0000
12       1.0000
13      -1.0000
```

Comment: How did you think to come up with this? Very impressive. Thanks for the answer!